# MATCH function does not work with numbers (only numbers) with wild cards (*)?

Tags: excel

I am trying to match pure numbers ending with *:

```
        A            B
1     52778*      5477A9
2     5477A*      527789
```

For example, I want to match A1 with B2, and the match function I used is:

```
=match(A1,B:B,0)
```

This should return the value of 2, but instead it gives me #N/A.

However, I found that I can successfully match A2 with B1:

```
=match(A2,B:B,0)
```

This gives me the result of 1....

Is it because the wild card (*) does not work with pure numbers? How can I match  pure numbers with wild card then?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`52778*` is text because of the `*`, `527789` is a number so the match doesn't work.

Format the number as text, or put an apostrophe in front of the number and it will work.

Edit - you could add another column to force numbers to text with the formula `=TEXT(B1,"#")` and then match on that.

Comment: =TEXT(B1,"#") works! It's interesting that manually changing to text under "format cells" does not work, but I have to use the formula to switch it to text. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to convert any numerics in column B to text.

If you cannot, for whatever reasons, perform this conversion on your actual data, you could use e.g.:

`=MATCH(A1,""&B1:B10,0)`

which, however, now requires entering as an `array formula`** and, as such, it would be a very bad idea indeed to reference entire columns (hence my choice of an upper row reference of 10).

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*